# Send Grid SMTP server sometimes can not connect

Tags: email, amazon-ec2, smtp, sendgrid

I am building a Jenkins server on my AWS EC2 instance.
 After building finish, I want to send email to stakeholder. 
I am using STMP with smtp.sendgrid.net in port 587. 
But I sometime can not send email. The log from jenkins says

> MessagingException message: Could not connect to SMTP host:
>   smtp.sendgrid.net, port: 587

I access to EC2 instance and telnet to sendgrid. It says:

> ```
> [hostname@domain ~]$ telnet smtp.sendgrid.net 587
> Trying 161.202.148.179...
> telnet: connect to address 161.202.148.179: Connection timed out
> Trying 161.202.148.182...
> telnet: connect to address 161.202.148.182: Connection timed out
> Trying 169.38.103.39...
> Connected to smtp.sendgrid.net.
> Escape character is '^]'.
> 220 SG ESMTP service ready at ismtpd0004p1maa1.sendgrid.net
> ```

I understand that mean I can only access to some ip coming from smtp.sendgrid domain. I am sure to open all outbound rules for EC2. 
Because the problem happens sometimes, so anyone could give me any suggestion for this situaions.
I intend to use IP instead of domain, but it just a workaround, IP can change anytime. 
Please help me.

Comment: Hi! did you fix it? I have the same issue

Comment: Not yet, using IP is acceptable for low-level important purpose.
I think it is a way people move to use Simple Email Service (Amazon SES)

Comment: I resolved the issue and posted the answer. Let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, if your EC2 outbound rules are opened then you should ensure that you provide SMTP authentication along with your SMTP server and SMTP port and your DNS resolvers are good enough.

Sendgrid expects username and password.

- username: it's "apikey", It might have to be encoded in base64 "YXBpa2V5".
- password: it's your API Key, get it from Sendgrid and save it here. It might have to be encoded in base64.

I tried base64 encoded and it didn't work, so I tried without the encoding and it worked.

If your problem is not related to the authentication, you could review your DNS resolver, probably the problem would be there.